# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError with flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app.

I have a form that looks like:

```
      <form class="form-inline" id="registerForm"  method="POST" action="/get_email/" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter your email address">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">submitMe!</button>
        </form>
```

This project uses flask-wtf to handle forms and in forms/user.py I've found:

```
class EmailForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
```

and a 'route' model that looks like:

```
@blueprint.route("/get_email/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_email():
    # form = EmailForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)
    form = EmailForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_user = User.create(email=form.email.data)
        flash("Thank you for registering. Please check your email to confirm signup.", 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('public.home'))
    else:
        flash_errors(form)
```

When I tested the email signup form (html above) by submitting only the email, I get :

jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError

```
UndefinedError: 'myflaskapp.forms.user.EmailForm object' has no attribute 'username'
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that you somewhere randomly in the templates indicated **form.username**. Maybe not in current but another. This is a mistake *Jinja* to look for templates. We will see what the file specifies interpreter and look at it. Here, unfortunately not the complete code and difficult to understand.

Also hint not relevant to the issue: check the requests POST:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
```